# Is it possible to dynamically select an element id and change its colour with JQuery when scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

As the list item scrolls up it changes colour and back again as it reaches the top or bottom of the window. Exactly as hoped. However is there a more elegant solution that uses just one function? I've been trying $(this) to select the target element when scrolling but I've not yet managed to crack it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var middleview = $(window).height()/2; //find middle of window
        var m = $( "#moving" );
      var mposition = m.position(); //get position of first element
        var d = $( "#dynamic" );
        var dposition = d.position(); //get position of second element
        var a = $( "#active" );
        var aposition = a.position(); //get position of third element
        var s = $( "#spirited" );
        var sposition = s.position(); //get position of fourth element
        var e = $( "#energetic" );
        var eposition = e.position(); //get position of fifth element
        var f = $( "#finish" );
        var fposition = f.position(); //get position of final element

      if ($(document).scrollTop() > mposition.top - middleview &&  $(document).scrollTop() < dposition.top - middleview) { //set colour change area
        $("#moving").removeClass("defaultcolor"); // remove default class
        $("#moving").addClass('color-' + $("#moving").data('color')); // change colour
      } else {
        $("#moving").removeClass('color-' + $("#moving").data('color')); // remove colour change
        $("#moving").addClass("defaultcolor"); // add default class
      }

     if ($(document).scrollTop() > dposition.top - middleview &&  $(document).scrollTop() < aposition.top - middleview) { //top then bottom
        $("#dynamic").removeClass("defaultcolor");
        $("#dynamic").addClass('color-' + $("#dynamic").data('color'));
      } else {
        $("#dynamic").removeClass('color-' + $("#dynamic").data('color'));
        $("#dynamic").addClass("defaultcolor");
      }

     if ($(document).scrollTop() > aposition.top - middleview &&  $(document).scrollTop() < sposition.top - middleview) { //top then bottom
        $("#active").removeClass("defaultcolor");
        $("#active").addClass('color-' + $("#active").data('color'));
      } else {
        $("#active").removeClass('color-' + $("#active").data('color'));
        $("#active").addClass("defaultcolor");
      }

     if ($(document).scrollTop() > sposition.top - middleview &&  $(document).scrollTop() < eposition.top - middleview) { //top then bottom
        $("#spirited").removeClass("defaultcolor");
        $("#spirited").addClass('color-' + $("#spirited").data('color'));
      } else {
        $("#spirited").removeClass('color-' + $("#spirited").data('color'));
        $("#spirited").addClass("defaultcolor");
      }

     if ($(document).scrollTop() > eposition.top - middleview &&  $(document).scrollTop() < fposition.top - middleview) { //top then bottom
        $("#energetic").removeClass("defaultcolor");
        $("#energetic").addClass('color-' + $("#energetic").data('color'));
      } else {
        $("#energetic").removeClass('color-' + $("#energetic").data('color'));
        $("#energetic").addClass("defaultcolor");
      }
    });
  });
```

```css
body {
    height:1550px;
    background-color: #f1f2eb;
    font-size: 3em;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
  }

  div {
    height:50%;
    }

  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    line-height: 300%;
  }

 .defaultcolor {
    color:white;
    transition: 1s;
 }

  .color-green {
    color: #095256;
    transition: 1s;
  }

  .color-orange {
    color: #e46e1e;
    transition: 1s;
  }

  .color-black {
    color: #C79F1C;
    transition: 1s;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div></div>
<ul>
 <li id="moving" class="defaultcolor" data-color="green">MOVING</li>
 <li id="dynamic" class="defaultcolor" data-color="orange">DYNAMIC</li>
 <li id="active" class="defaultcolor" data-color="black">ACTIVE</li>
 <li id="spirited" class="defaultcolor" data-color="orange">SPIRITED</li>
 <li id="energetic" class="defaultcolor" data-color="green">ENERGETIC</li>
</ul>
<z id="finish"></z>
<div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible! See the below snippet. Instead of defining ids just loop through all the elements (I gave them a class of .colortext) and perform your action. If the next() element doesn't exist, I set it to the finish element that you have.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var middleview = $(window).height() / 2; //find middle of window
    $('.colortext').each((_, text) => {
      var textElem = $(text);
      var top = $(document).scrollTop();
      var color = textElem.data('color');
      var next = textElem.next();
      if (next.length === 0) {
        next = $('#finish');
      }

      if (top > textElem.position().top - middleview && top < next.position().top - middleview) { // set colour change area
        textElem.removeClass("defaultcolor"); // remove default class
        textElem.addClass('color-' + color); // change colour
      } else {
        textElem.removeClass('color-' + color); // remove colour change
        textElem.addClass("defaultcolor"); // add default class
      }
    })
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1550px;
  background-color: #f1f2eb;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  height: 50%;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 300%;
}

.defaultcolor {
  color: white;
  transition: 1s;
}

.color-green {
  color: #095256;
  transition: 1s;
}

.color-orange {
  color: #e46e1e;
  transition: 1s;
}

.color-black {
  color: #C79F1C;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<ul>
  <li id="moving" class="colortext defaultcolor" data-color="green">MOVING</li>
  <li id="dynamic" class="colortext defaultcolor" data-color="orange">DYNAMIC</li>
  <li id="active" class="colortext defaultcolor" data-color="black">ACTIVE</li>
  <li id="spirited" class="colortext defaultcolor" data-color="orange">SPIRITED</li>
  <li id="energetic" class="colortext defaultcolor" data-color="green">ENERGETIC</li>
</ul>
<z id="finish"></z>
<div></div>
```